# Coverting Encrypted HLS to MP4 clear

Tags: mp4, http-live-streaming, playready

Can anyone advise on how to construct an MP4 file from an HLS stream encrypted with Playready (the reverse of what you usually do)? I have the m3u8 a and encryption key - is there a straightforward way of getting a single MP4 using FFMPEG or some other tool?

Answer (score 0):

Unified Streaming offer a solution with one of their tools:

http://docs.unified-streaming.com/documentation/capture/usage.html#decrypt

FFMPEG may offer a solution as well, but this is what we use. (I don't work for Unified Streaming)